# Extracting Y values from a plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to get some data from a plot by using `ggplot_build()`.
This is the code with which I create the plot:

```
mapping <- aes(
  x = values
  , color = factor(par_a)
)

plot <- (ggplot(data=data, mapping=mapping)
         + geom_freqpoly(binwidth = 5, na.rm = TRUE)
         + facet_grid(par_b ~ par_c ~ par_d, scales = "free")
)
```

And this is how it looks:
[image: pic 2]

So `ggplot_build(plot)`  gives the following output:

```
       colour      y  count    x   xmin   xmax width      density       ncount     ndensity flipped_aes PANEL group size
1     #F8766D      0      0  -10  -12.5   -7.5     5 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00       FALSE     1     1  0.5
2     #F8766D      2      2   -5   -7.5   -2.5     5 2.557774e-06 1.211681e-04 1.211681e-04       FALSE     1     1  0.5
3     #F8766D   8977   8977    0   -2.5    2.5     5 1.148057e-02 5.438628e-01 5.438628e-01       FALSE     1     1  0.5
4     #F8766D  16506  16506    5    2.5    7.5     5 2.110931e-02 1.000000e+00 1.000000e+00       FALSE     1     1  0.5
5     #F8766D  14355  14355   10    7.5   12.5     5 1.835842e-02 8.696838e-01 8.696838e-01       FALSE     1     1  0.5
6     #F8766D  12823  12823   15   12.5   17.5     5 1.639917e-02 7.768690e-01 7.768690e-01       FALSE     1     1  0.5
7     #F8766D  11843  11843   20   17.5   22.5     5 1.514586e-02 7.174967e-01 7.174967e-01       FALSE     1     1  0.5
8     #F8766D  10379  10379   25   22.5   27.5     5 1.327357e-02 6.288016e-01 6.288016e-01       FALSE     1     1  0.5
9     #F8766D   9717   9717   30   27.5   32.5     5 1.242694e-02 5.886950e-01 5.886950e-01       FALSE     1     1  0.5
10    #F8766D   8765   8765   35   32.5   37.5     5 1.120944e-02 5.310190e-01 5.310190e-01       FALSE     1     1  0.5
11    #F8766D   7626   7626   40   37.5   42.5     5 9.752791e-03 4.620138e-01 4.620138e-01       FALSE     1     1  0.5
12    #F8766D   7113   7113   45   42.5   47.5     5 9.096722e-03 4.309342e-01 4.309342e-01       FALSE     1     1  0.5
13    #F8766D   6107   6107   50   47.5   52.5     5 7.810162e-03 3.699867e-01 3.699867e-01       FALSE     1     1  0.5
14    #F8766D   5391   5391   55   52.5   57.5     5 6.894479e-03 3.266085e-01 3.266085e-01       FALSE     1     1  0.5
15    #F8766D   4802   4802   60   57.5   62.5     5 6.141215e-03 2.909245e-01 2.909245e-01       FALSE     1     1  0.5
16    #F8766D   4287   4287   65   62.5   67.5     5 5.482588e-03 2.597237e-01 2.597237e-01       FALSE     1     1  0.5
17    #F8766D   4009   4009   70   67.5   72.5     5 5.127057e-03 2.428814e-01 2.428814e-01       FALSE     1     1  0.5
18    #F8766D   3374   3374   75   72.5   77.5     5 4.314964e-03 2.044105e-01 2.044105e-01       FALSE     1     1  0.5
19    #F8766D   2935   2935   80   77.5   82.5     5 3.753533e-03 1.778141e-01 1.778141e-01       FALSE     1     1  0.5
20    #F8766D   2608   2608   85   82.5   87.5     5 3.335337e-03 1.580032e-01 1.580032e-01       FALSE     1     1  0.5
21    #F8766D   2220   2220   90   87.5   92.5     5 2.839129e-03 1.344965e-01 1.344965e-01       FALSE     1     1  0.5
22    #F8766D   1914   1914   95   92.5   97.5     5 2.447789e-03 1.159578e-01 1.159578e-01       FALSE     1     1  0.5
23    #F8766D   1685   1685  100   97.5  102.5     5 2.154924e-03 1.020841e-01 1.020841e-01       FALSE     1     1  0.5
24    #F8766D   1429   1429  105  102.5  107.5     5 1.827529e-03 8.657458e-02 8.657458e-02       FALSE     1     1  0.5
25    #F8766D   1272   1272  110  107.5  112.5     5 1.626744e-03 7.706289e-02 7.706289e-02       FALSE     1     1  0.5
26    #F8766D   1071   1071  115  112.5  117.5     5 1.369688e-03 6.488550e-02 6.488550e-02       FALSE     1     1  0.5
27    #F8766D    869    869  120  117.5  122.5     5 1.111353e-03 5.264752e-02 5.264752e-02       FALSE     1     1  0.5
28    #F8766D    743    743  125  122.5  127.5     5 9.502129e-04 4.501393e-02 4.501393e-02       FALSE     1     1  0.5
29    #F8766D    678    678  130  127.5  132.5     5 8.670853e-04 4.107597e-02 4.107597e-02       FALSE     1     1  0.5
30    #F8766D    561    561  135  132.5  137.5     5 7.174555e-04 3.398764e-02 3.398764e-02       FALSE     1     1  0.5
31    #F8766D    452    452  140  137.5  142.5     5 5.780569e-04 2.738398e-02 2.738398e-02       FALSE     1     1  0.5
32    #F8766D    313    313  145  142.5  147.5     5 4.002916e-04 1.896280e-02 1.896280e-02       FALSE     1     1  0.5
33    #F8766D    290    290  150  147.5  152.5     5 3.708772e-04 1.756937e-02 1.756937e-02       FALSE     1     1  0.5
34    #F8766D    229    229  155  152.5  157.5     5 2.928651e-04 1.387374e-02 1.387374e-02       FALSE     1     1  0.5
35    #F8766D    200    200  160  157.5  162.5     5 2.557774e-04 1.211681e-02 1.211681e-02       FALSE     1     1  0.5
36    #F8766D    171    171  165  162.5  167.5     5 2.186897e-04 1.035987e-02 1.035987e-02       FALSE     1     1  0.5
37    #F8766D    128    128  170  167.5  172.5     5 1.636975e-04 7.754756e-03 7.754756e-03       FALSE     1     1  0.5
38    #F8766D     92     92  175  172.5  177.5     5 1.176576e-04 5.573731e-03 5.573731e-03       FALSE     1     1  0.5
39    #F8766D     87     87  180  177.5  182.5     5 1.112632e-04 5.270811e-03 5.270811e-03       FALSE     1     1  0.5
40    #F8766D     73     73  185  182.5  187.5     5 9.335874e-05 4.422634e-03 4.422634e-03       FALSE     1     1  0.5
41    #F8766D     61     61  190  187.5  192.5     5 7.801210e-05 3.695626e-03 3.695626e-03       FALSE     1     1  0.5
42    #F8766D     44     44  195  192.5  197.5     5 5.627102e-05 2.665697e-03 2.665697e-03       FALSE     1     1  0.5
43    #F8766D     50     50  200  197.5  202.5     5 6.394434e-05 3.029202e-03 3.029202e-03       FALSE     1     1  0.5
44    #F8766D     35     35  205  202.5  207.5     5 4.476104e-05 2.120441e-03 2.120441e-03       FALSE     1     1  0.5
45    #F8766D     21     21  210  207.5  212.5     5 2.685662e-05 1.272265e-03 1.272265e-03       FALSE     1     1  0.5
46    #F8766D     17     17  215  212.5  217.5     5 2.174108e-05 1.029929e-03 1.029929e-03       FALSE     1     1  0.5
47    #F8766D     15     15  220  217.5  222.5     5 1.918330e-05 9.087605e-04 9.087605e-04       FALSE     1     1  0.5
48    #F8766D     13     13  225  222.5  227.5     5 1.662553e-05 7.875924e-04 7.875924e-04       FALSE     1     1  0.5
49    #F8766D      7      7  230  227.5  232.5     5 8.952208e-06 4.240882e-04 4.240882e-04       FALSE     1     1  0.5
50    #F8766D      9      9  235  232.5  237.5     5 1.150998e-05 5.452563e-04 5.452563e-04       FALSE     1     1  0.5
51    #F8766D      6      6  240  237.5  242.5     5 7.673321e-06 3.635042e-04 3.635042e-04       FALSE     1     1  0.5
52    #F8766D      4      4  245  242.5  247.5     5 5.115547e-06 2.423361e-04 2.423361e-04       FALSE     1     1  0.5
53    #F8766D      3      3  250  247.5  252.5     5 3.836661e-06 1.817521e-04 1.817521e-04       FALSE     1     1  0.5
54    #F8766D      1      1  255  252.5  257.5     5 1.278887e-06 6.058403e-05 6.058403e-05       FALSE     1     1  0.5
55    #F8766D      1      1  260  257.5  262.5     5 1.278887e-06 6.058403e-05 6.058403e-05       FALSE     1     1  0.5
56    #F8766D      1      1  265  262.5  267.5     5 1.278887e-06 6.058403e-05 6.058403e-05       FALSE     1     1  0.5
57    #F8766D      1      1  270  267.5  272.5     5 1.278887e-06 6.058403e-05 6.058403e-05       FALSE     1     1  0.5
58    #F8766D      0      0  275  272.5  277.5     5 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00       FALSE     1     1  0.5
59    #F8766D      0      0  280  277.5  282.5     5 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00       FALSE     1     1  0.5
60    #F8766D      0      0  285  282.5  287.5     5 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00       FALSE     1     1  0.5
61    #F8766D      0      0  290  287.5  292.5     5 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00       FALSE     1     1  0.5
62    #F8766D      1      1  295  292.5  297.5     5 1.278887e-06 6.058403e-05 6.058403e-05       FALSE     1     1  0.5
```

The output doesn't really make sense to me, since I want to get the values used to plot each LINE on the plot. Meaning, in the end, I want to have 60plots * 2lines = 120 **VECTORS** with values.  With the used function I was hoping to get under Y the desired values but it doesn't seem to be the case.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your data, `PANEL` is the facet panel and `group` is the color group. Your data has many more rows - it just showed the first 62 due to max print limitations.

Recreating the plot with dummy data.

```
df <- tibble(
  x = runif(100),
  group1 = sample(factor(1:2), 100, replace = TRUE),
  group2 = sample(1:4, 100, replace = TRUE),
  group3 = sample(1:2, 100, replace = TRUE),
  group4 = sample(1:2, 100, replace = TRUE)
)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, colour = group1)) +
  geom_freqpoly(binwidth = 5, na.rm = TRUE) +
  facet_grid(~group2~group3~group4)
p
```

[image: p]

`data` inside the result of `ggplot_build` contains the plot data.

```
plot_data <- tibble(ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]])
plot_data
#> # A tibble: 87 x 16
#> colour     y count     x  xmin  xmax width density ncount ndensity flipped_aes PANEL group
#> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl> <lgl>       <fct> <int>
#>   1 #F876~     0     0    -5  -7.5  -2.5     5    0         0        0 FALSE       1         1
#> 2 #F876~     3     3     0  -2.5   2.5     5    0.20      1        1 FALSE       1         1
#> 3 #F876~     0     0     5   2.5   7.5     5    0         0        0 FALSE       1         1
#> 4 #F876~     0     0    -5  -7.5  -2.5     5    0         0        0 FALSE       2         1
#> 5 #F876~     2     2     0  -2.5   2.5     5    0.2       1        1 FALSE       2         1
#> 6 #F876~     0     0     5   2.5   7.5     5    0         0        0 FALSE       2         1
#> 7 #00BF~     0     0    -5  -7.5  -2.5     5    0         0        0 FALSE       2         2
#> 8 #00BF~     5     5     0  -2.5   2.5     5    0.2       1        1 FALSE       2         2
#> 9 #00BF~     0     0     5   2.5   7.5     5    0         0        0 FALSE       2         2
#> 10 #F876~     0     0    -5  -7.5  -2.5     5    0         0        0 FALSE       3         1
#> # ... with 77 more rows, and 3 more variables: size <dbl>, linetype <dbl>, alpha <lgl>
```

`PANEL` is the facet panel and `group` is the color group. The individual lines can be plotted like this.

```
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x, y, col = paste(plot_data$PANEL, d$group))) + geom_line()
```

[image: p2]

Comment: My goal is to extract the values in vectors and save them to data frame. For example 'df <- c(group1,group2,group3,group4,values)' . You say that the data has more rows, but they are not shown, so if I go for 'ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]$y' I would get a lot of values, however I wont be able to sort them based on the groups they belong to